# How to decrypt read data using session key and initial vector in 3DES

Tags: java, android, cryptography, mifare, contactless-smartcard

I have an android app and trying to read, write desfire ev1 tag in 3DES mode.
I got all commands successful: ... create application, authenticate with new application, create std file in the new application, read the new file.
I think i have correct session key from successful rndA rndB.

the file is in enchipher mode, and when I try to decrypt with session key with 0 IV, I don't get correct data(all zero) + crc + padding (zeros) but some random data.

if I create file with plain text I get correct read data (all zero)

Simply Im not really sure how to use IV. Is the IV not supposed to be 0? if so when and how IV is updated before the read file response to decrypt?

Thanks!